# I don't know why I receive this message in angular: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typeerror

I have an array of JSON in an angular component and I want to move it to another array.

declaration of types :

MeasurementDetails :

```
export interface MeasurementDetails {
  _id: string;
  measureTitle: string;
  measureDescription: string;
  measureSymbol: string;
}
```

and MeasureTypeElemetns :

```
export interface MeasureTypeElemetns {
  title: string;
  position: number;
  description: string;
  symbol: string;
}
```

I declared two arrays with initialization like this :

```
mp: MeasurementDetails[] = [];
ELEMENT_DATA: MeasureTypeElemetns[] = [];
```

I requested an HTTP request and it responded me. 
I called it in constructor of component class like this:

```
  this.mpserv.getall().subscribe(
    x => {
      x.forEach(elementj => {
        this.mp.push(elementj);
      });
      this.filltoelements(this.mp);
    },
    err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
    () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
  );
```

"filltoelements" function declared like this:

```
filltoelements(mdata: MeasurementDetails[]) {
  if (!mdata) {
    console.log('data is undefined!!!!');
  } else {
    let i = -1;
    mdata.forEach(elementi => {
      i++;
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].position = (i + 1);
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].title = elementi.measureTitle;
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].description = elementi.measureDescription;
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].symbol = elementi.measureSymbol;
    });
  }
}
```

But when I run, it shows a message :

```
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined
     at measure-type.component.ts:74
     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
     at MeasureTypeComponent.push../src/app/cc/measurement/measure- 
 type/measure-type.component.ts.MeasureTypeComponent.filltoelements"
```

I think this is related to initialization of my 'ELEMENT_DATA' array. but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ELEMENT_DATA` is empty array so it returns `undefined` element.

Just assign a empty object like `this.ELEMENT_DATA[i] = {}` before access to its property.

This code will work.

```ts
filltoelements(mdata: MeasurementDetails[]) {
  if (!mdata) {
    console.log('data is undefined!!!!');
  } else {
    let i = -1;
    mdata.forEach(elementi => {
      i++;
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i] = {} as MeasureTypeElemetns;
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].position = (i + 1);
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].title = elementi.measureTitle;
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].description = elementi.measureDescription;
      this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].symbol = elementi.measureSymbol;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It caught an error :
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MeasureTypeElemetns': title, position, description, symbolts(2739)

I used this instead of {} :
this.ELEMENT_DATA[i] = { title: '', position: 0, description: '', symbol: ''};

Comment: It's typing issue. Change code to `{} as MeasureTypeElemetns`. I've updated my post.